# Send http get via c# in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, http, get

Im trying to send this data:

```
GET /sms/send?number=4793224070&message=hei HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic bmV0Y89tOm3ldJNvbXh5eg==
User-Agent: Java1.3.1_01
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

As a http get request via c#. I have read the Learn c# in one day and understand a bit c# but I can't seem to figure this out. I have gotten this far:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://firebolt.netcom.no:8080/sms/send");
```

Comment: The code got scrambled. Here is link to the paste code: https://paste.ofcode.org/iSQeRWjWHi39CQakPnep7i

Comment: It didn't "get scrambled", you just didn't format it properly.

Comment: you haven't included the querystring on the url

Comment: Could anyone Point me in the right direction? Or show me how its dine. I cant seem to figure IT out

Answer (score 0):

Get Data is include inside the URL Post data is included in your request.

This is what i typically use:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

//Get request
//                                                                              | GET DATA                   |
string response = client.DownloadString("http://firebolt.netcom.no:8080/sms/send?number=4793224070&message=hei");

//Post request
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection(); //Stores post data
nvc.Add("number", "4793224070"); //value 1
nvc.Add("message", "hei"); //value 2
byte [] tmp = client.UploadValues("http://url.com/", nvc); //request
response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmp);
```

Comment: I still dont understand.....
What do i do with this to get it to do a request?

string response = client.DownloadString("http://firebolt.netcom.no:8080/sms/send?number=4793224070&message=hei");